# Updating all column's values right after calling query builder in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

My database is currently saying time in UTC.
What I want is to convert the time to another time, which I know how it's done, but how can I do it right after querying?

For example:

```
DB::table('notes')->where();
```

This will give me more than one result and I want to change the `created_at` column before chaining it to `->select('contents', 'created_at')->get()`.

Is it possible?
Or do I have to do `->get()` first then reassign the `created_at` after? Which is what I am doing at the moment but I don't want to do it before chaining other methods.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.